# View access based on roles

Tags: views, 8, users

I have 1 view /admin/people, and its 2 display, both are of type page.

I want `display = page` will be shown to admin role while `display = LMA` is for xyz role.

After setting roles for 2 different pages with same access url /admin/people, I logged as admin role and xyz role. Display for admin role is working fine, but for xyz role, it says access denied.

Whats the correct way to have views display for different roles.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

This didn't work for me either. I worked around this one by creating a panel page and using two different variants, placing each view block in the appropriate page and restricting the access based on user roles.